# Limit number of S3 uploads / SNS notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

We have an external service that uploads files to our `S3 bucket` in `account A`. We raise `SNS notifications` on each upload. A `lambda` function in `account B` subscribes to these notifications.

This works well for us, except that **if the external service misses a configuration, it uploads >500 files together (in a single directory)**. And our lambda is triggered 500 times when that happens.

```
1. Is there a way to limit the number of files uploaded to a bucket within X minutes?
2. Is there a way to stop the lambda from getting invoked if it sees >500 SNS notifications together?
```

I am aware that placing an SQS between the Lambda and SNS will probably solve our problem. I want to know if there is another easier, more convenient way to solve this.

I explored the possibility of limiting the lambda concurrency so that is fails on throttling, however SNS notifications will be retried thrice (which is also a good thing and we don't want to lose this feature in case of other errors), so we do not want to do that.

Note that instant processing is not a hard requirement for us. We can wait for around 5 minutes to process the SNS notification.

Comment: What is your particular problem? How does raising these 500 requests have an impact on your system? Are there other subscribers to the SNS topic?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The problem is that this will happen only due to misconfiguration at the external service. And the SNS notification message should not be processed at our end. But we have no other way of knowing this, because the message is the same for a valid / invalid notification. The only way to know is the irregular shoot in the number of these notifications.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - (Continuing) I could check the directory for the number of files (we expect only 1 file in a directory, but due to this misconfiguration, we will have 500 files), but I would be doing that 500 times, and something I want to avoid.

Comment: If this potential problem can be avoided by having the Lambda function count the number of objects in a particular S3 path, then this sounds like a good ting to do.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The processing of the SNS notification can be avoided by counting the number of objects in a particular S3 path, correct. But I would prefer to stop the lambda from being invoked >500 times. Hence looking for a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to limit uploads to Amazon S3 within a given time period.

Nor is it possible to stop Lambda being invoked if it sees more than a given quantity of Amazon SNS notifications.

Comment: So your suggestion would be to go ahead with SQS to limit this?